# Error: 'dagster.core.types.runtime' is not a package

Tags: python, dagster

Installed dagster for the first time in a conda environment and tried to run the airline demo as described [here](https://dagster.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.6/sections/learn/airline_demo.html).  The following are the steps I followed.

```
conda env create -n dagster python=3.7
conda activate dagster
pip install dagster dagit
git clone git@github.com/dagster-io/dagster.git
cd dagster/examples
pip install -e '[.full]'
docker-compose up -d
cd dagster_examples/airline_demo
dagit
```

I then get the following stack trace ending in the `'dagster.core.types.runtime' is not a package` message:

```
Loading repository...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/bin/dagit-cli", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagit/cli.py", line 110, in main
    cli = create_dagit_cli()
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagit/cli.py", line 21, in create_dagit_cli
    return ui(auto_envvar_prefix='DAGIT')  # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagit/cli.py", line 72, in ui
    host_dagit_ui(handle, host, port, storage_fallback, reload_trigger)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagit/cli.py", line 81, in host_dagit_ui
    app = create_app(handle, instance, reloader)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagit/app.py", line 160, in create_app
    version=__version__,
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster_graphql/implementation/context.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.repository_definition = self.get_handle().build_repository_definition()
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/handle.py", line 392, in build_repository_definition
    obj = self.entrypoint.perform_load()
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/handle.py", line 445, in entrypoint
    return self.data.get_repository_entrypoint(from_handle=self)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/handle.py", line 522, in get_repository_entrypoint
    return LoaderEntrypoint.from_yaml(self.repository_yaml, from_handle=from_handle)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/handle.py", line 175, in from_yaml
    return LoaderEntrypoint.from_module_target(module_name, fn_name, from_handle)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/handle.py", line 161, in from_module_target
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/miniconda3/envs/dagster/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/Projects/dagster/dagster/examples/dagster_examples/airline_demo/repository.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pipelines import define_airline_demo_ingest_pipeline, define_airline_demo_warehouse_pipeline
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/Projects/dagster/dagster/examples/dagster_examples/airline_demo/pipelines.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .resources import postgres_db_info_resource, redshift_db_info_resource
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/Projects/dagster/dagster/examples/dagster_examples/airline_demo/resources.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .types import DbInfo
  File "/Users/timrozmajzl/Projects/dagster/dagster/examples/dagster_examples/airline_demo/types.py", line 8, in <module>
    from dagster.core.types.runtime.runtime_type import create_string_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dagster.core.types.runtime.runtime_type'; 'dagster.core.types.runtime' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue! After some digging, it seems like this [commit](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/commit/5e69b75a3fbbe7b1ab48cc20c357efca2ccddd81#diff-5fbd2faed6625f26c4912b7fdacb85db) was not compatible with the latest release of dagster (at the time) which caused the error.

Re-running this workflow with the most recent dagster master and dependencies should resolve this. [Opening an issue here](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/issues/2451) to track a more long-term fix.

More details: In this [commit](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/commit/5e69b75a3fbbe7b1ab48cc20c357efca2ccddd81#diff-5fbd2faed6625f26c4912b7fdacb85db), 'create_string_type' is introduced to both 'examples/dagster_examples/airline_demo/types.py' and 'python_modules/dagster/dagster/core/types/runtime/runtime_type.py'. However, based on the commands pasted in the question and present in the [airline demo steps](https://docs.dagster.io/docs/learn/demos/airline_demo), airline_demo pipeline was running the tip of master (which contained 'create_string_type') with an older dagster package (from the latest release, which did not contain 'create_string_type').